# How to convert multiple String Array to ArrayList<FileItems> in Java

Tags: java, android

I have **mListResult** have **size = 10**;
I have a Contructor **FileItems**
This is class ***FileItems***
    public class FileItems {

```
private String mTitle;
private String mFileId;

public FileItems(String mTitle, String mFileId) {
    this.mTitle = mTitle;
    this.mFileId = mFileId;
}

public FileItems() {
}

public String getTitle() {
    return mTitle;
}

public void setTitle(String mTitle) {
    this.mTitle = mTitle;
}

public String getFileId() {
    return mFileId;
}

public void setFileId(String mFileId) {
    this.mFileId = mFileId;
}
```

}

this is Activity

```
  List<FileItems> mListFileItems=new ArrayList<FileItems>();
  String mFileArray[] = new String[mResultList.size()];
  String mDownloadUrl[] = new String[mResultList.size()];
  FileItems fileItems = new FileItems();
            int i = 0;
            for (File tmp : mResultList) {
                //System.out.println("FILE DATA "+tmp.getId()+"."+tmp.getFileSize()+".."+tmp.getFileExtension()+",,"+tmp.getMimeType()+"/"+tmp.getTitle());
              mFileArray[i] = tmp.getTitle();
              mDownloadUrl[i] = tmp.getId();
                i++;
                fileItems.setTitle(tmp.getTitle());
                fileItems.setFileId(tmp.getId());
                mListFileItems.add(fileItems);
            }
```

I use Debug Tesst

```
            DebugTool.logD("LISTTTTTT " + mFileArray.length());
            DebugTool.logD("LISTTTTTT " + mDownloadUrl.length());
            DebugTool.logD("LISTTTTTT " + mListFileItems.size());
            DebugTool.logD("LISTTTTTT " + mListFileItems.get(1).getTitle());
            DebugTool.logD("LISTTTTTT " + mListFileItems.get(0).getTitle());
            DebugTool.logD("LISTTTTTT " + mListFileItems.get(2).getTitle());
```

This is result

```
 05-13 10:31:17.063 3561-3561/test.com D/TAG: LISTTTTTT 10
 05-13 10:31:17.063 3561-3561/test.com D/TAG: LISTTTTTT 10
 05-13 10:31:17.063 3561-3561/test.com D/TAG: LISTTTTTT 10
 05-13 10:31:17.063 3561-3561/test.com D/TAG: LISTTTTTT Test1.pptx
 05-13 10:31:17.063 3561-3561/test.com D/TAG: LISTTTTTT Test1.pptx
 05-13 10:31:17.063 3561-3561/test.com D/TAG: LISTTTTTT Test1.pptx
```

I use code above. It return only a element. Please Help me!!!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: getTitle() have Test1, Test2, Test3. But It return only a element. Help me!

Comment: `element` what is that mean... I think you are saying need file name without its extension Right?

Comment: it is value. How to I can add two String Array to ArrayList have use a model FileItems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting same result because the object you are setting values in loop is always same(means not new object)

```
    FileItems fileItems = null;
    int i = 0;
    for (File tmp : mResultList) {

        mFileArray[i] = tmp.getTitle();
        mDownloadUrl[i] = tmp.getId();
        i++;

        fileItems=new FileItems();//create new object for every new item

        fileItems.setTitle(tmp.getTitle());
        fileItems.setFileId(tmp.getId());
        mListFileItems.add(fileItems);
    }
```

Comment: It worked !!! Thanks you very much !!